# php foreach cycle with counter to prevent echo of first and last lines

Tags: php, string, foreach, cycle

I'm trying to make a little script to manipulate a txt file with a given directory file contents. What happens is that the text file generated by going to Win command line and execute "dir > file.txt" has lines that are junk to this purpous... like the first 7 lines and last 3. These ones:

```
O volume na unidade C nao tem nome.
O numero de serie do volume - F879-0704

Directorio de C:\xampp\htdocs\projectX\images\

06-01-2012  14:56    <DIR>          .
06-01-2012  14:56    <DIR>          ..
.
.
.
140 ficheiro(s)        5.676.057 bytes
2 dir(s)        307.888.893.952 bytes livres
```

The code I have so far is this:

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
$data = fread($fp, filesize($file));
fclose($fp);

$end = 0;
$i = 0;

while($end != 1) {

$output = str_replace("\t|\t", " | ", $data);
$output = explode("\n", $output);

foreach($output as $var) {
    if($i > 7){
      $newstring = substr($var, 36);
      echo "File: " . $newstring . "<br />"; 
    }
    $i++;
}       
echo "<br /><strong>End of file list!</strong>";
$end = 1;
```

}

**My Question:** How can I get this foreach cycle to ignore the last lines of the text file too ?

Comment: You're better of building something more intuitive than ignoring certain line numbers. That's brittle. Instead, build logic that matches the lines you care about (i.e. string or regex matching)

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to get all files in a directory or something like that. There are far better methods for this if that is the case. The most basic form is demonstrated here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Comment: Why do you list the directories using `dir` when PHP has functions like [`scandir()`](http://php.net/scandir)?

Comment: Yeah Jason, I know I should do that but the problem is that I don't have the knowledge needed to do that in the time frame I have for this :) But if you care to help me there, all lines are like this: 06-01-2012  13:31            38.915 nm0005013.jpg (I just need the file name! Nothing else) Thanks for taking the time to comment

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen: That question has a fantastic easy answer! With PHP I'll incline faster to the noob side than to the expert side :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably use [`scandir()`](http://php.net/scandir) or equivalent PHP functions that are specifically made for this.

If you insist, however, you can either slice up the array using [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice). The following will remove the two first and last lines.

```
$output = array_slice($output, 2, count($output) - 4);
```

Alternatively, you could just iterate over the part you want with a [`for`](http://php.net/while) loop instead of a `foreach` loop.

```
$files = (count($output)-2);
for ($file=7; $file < $files; $file++)
  $newstring = substr($output[$file, 36);
  echo "File: " . $newstring . "<br />"; 
}
```

Comment: You're solution worked great for now! And I'll follow your suggestion and use scandir() when I have some free time. I completely forgot that function even existed! What a dumb idiot! :) Anyway, I love StackOverflow exactly for this, we can learn a lot from asking a dumb question! Thank you and Thanks all for the great suggestions. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could do something like this:

```
$total = count($output);
foreach($output as $var) {
    if ($i > 7 && $i < $total - 1) {
        $newstring = substr($var, 36);
        echo "File: ".$newstring."<br />";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

I agree with @Jason McCreary in the comments on the question, though.  This is not anything close to an elegant solution.  But it will do for your exact situation.  Alternatively, if you aren't forced to work from your text file, you could follow the code example for the [opendir()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) function and parse the directory contents that way.

Comment: you want to use && and instead of || or

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_slice()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to chop the $output array down to just the entries you need before looping.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code around the `if` statement to look like this:

```
$total = count($output) - 3;
if($i > 7 && $i < $total) {
```

Comment: calling count on each iteration of the loop is a little inefficient

Comment: You're right. I modified it as i had an error in the if statement aswell.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$lastLine=count($output)-3;
for($i=7; $i<$lastLine; $i++) {
    $newstring = substr($var, 36);
    echo "File: " . $newstring . "<br />"; 
}
```

Comment: With this code you still iterate over the last lines even though you don't need them. That's just extra work. Instead, you should add `if ($i<($lastLine-3)) break;` at the beginning. Or simply use a `for loop`.

Comment: yes. thinking about it a for loop is more appropriate than a foreach loop. Im adjusting my code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would store all the lines into an array, splice out the lines you need, and then echo it all.

```
//ADD FILE LINES TO ARRAY
foreach($output as $var) {
   $file_lines[] = substr($var, 36)."\n"; 
}

//SPLICE OUT LINES NEEDED
$newlines = array_splice($file_lines, 7, count($file_lines)-3);

//ECHO DATA
foreach($newlines as $line) {
   echo $line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can list files of specified directory with help of php code http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dir.php.